# Expectation of the mean of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

If $X_i$'s are independent and identified random variables, each with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let's say $S_m = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m X_i,~~ m = 1,2,\ldots,M.$ What are the values of $\mathbb {E}[S_m]$ and $Var(S_m)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Fill the ? in $S_m^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^m ?$ so you can take $\langle S_m^2 \rangle$.

Comment: I got $\mathbb {E}[S_m]=\mathbb {E}[\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m X_i]=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb {E}[X_i]=\mu$. But it's too routine to believe it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ hence we have:
$$E(S_m) = \frac{m*\mu}{m}$$
$$E(S_m) = \mu $$
Recall that $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$.
Also recall that $Var(cX) - c^2 Var(x)$ hence we have:
$$Var(\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m X_i,~~ m = 1,2,\ldots,M) = m \sigma^2$$
$$Var(S_m) = \frac{m \sigma^2}{m^2}$$
$$Var(S_m) = \frac{\sigma^2}{m}$$

I hope that helps.

Bob

Comment: These answers are wrong because you didn't divide by $m$ when considering $S_m$.

Comment: @Shalop You are right. I will fix me post.

Comment: So it should be $\mathbb {E}(S_m)=\mu$ and $Var(S_m)=\frac {\sigma^2}{m}$.